# How to validate inputs from GET request in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I wanted to validate inputs from a GET request without using the

this->validate($request... or \Validator::make($request...

and prefer to do it like

$input = $request->validate([... rules ...]);

however since get requests doesn't have $request parameters how can I achieve it?

```
public function sampleGet($param1, $param2) {

     // How can I pass the $param1 and $param to to validate?
     $input = $request->validate([
         'param1' => 'required',
         'param2' => 'required  
     ]);
}
```

Comment: Which one do you mean `example.com/param1/param2` or `example.com?param1=test&param2=test` ?

Comment: in this example the inputs are from route parameters.. Route::get('/sample/{param1}/{param2}', 'Controller@sampleGet');

Comment: @mmabdelgawad the example.com/param1/param2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so and it will have same behavior as `validate`

```
validator($request->route()->parameters(), [

    'param1' => 'required',
    'param2' => 'required'
    ....

])->validate();
```

Comment: I think this would work for me..but since I'm passing the route parameters already in the method I'll use `compact('param1', 'param2')` instead of `$request->route()->parameters()`

Answer (score 3):

If you want all the route parameters you can get them as an array:

```
$request->route()->parameters()
```

Since you already have those parameters being passed to your method you can just build an array with them:

```
compact('param1', 'param2');
// or
['param1' => $param1, 'param2' => $param2];
```

You are not going to be using the `validate` method on the Request though, you will have to manually create a validator. Unless you want to merge this array into the request or create a new request with these as inputs.

There is nothing special about the `validate` method on a Controller or on a Request. They are all making a validator and validating the data the same way you would yourself.

When manually creating a validator you still have a `validate` method that will throw an exception, which would be the equivalent to what is happening on Request and the Controller with their `validate` methods.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Validation - Manualy Creating Validators - Automatic Redirection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#automatic-redirection)

Comment: but my problem is how can I pass the parameters on $input = $request->validate([.. rules ..]); for validation

Comment: the last paragraph of the answer goes into that

Comment: so there's no way I can use the validate method to validate route parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that.

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{
  try {
       $input['route1'] = $request->route('route1');
       $input['route2'] = $request->route('route2');
       $valid = Validator::make($input, [
            'route1' => 'required',
            'route2' => 'required'
         ]);
  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    echo "<pre>";print_r($th->__toString());die;
  }
}
```

Or you can follow the below link for more info.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Answer (score 0):

You can use Validator class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


        $request = Request::capture();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->query(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // Do something with the failed validation
            dd("test");
        }
```